# basic javascript and knockout.js in MVC 3 app: problem with for in loop over an array of myCustomObject items

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

### Problem:

I am trying to use knockout.js with jquery templates.  The problem is that an $.ajax call returns values correctly, but when I try to insert them into the corresponding `ko.observableArray`, I get the correct number of rows, but the values are all `undefined`

The problem, according to my debugging is located in a for in loop in the success callback for an $.ajax call.

It seems that if I write:

```
for (item in myArray)
{
    alert(item.myProperty); // shows undefined
}
```

What am I doing wrong??!

Detailed setup follows.

### Setup:

My template is:

```
<fieldset style="padding-top:10px;">
    <legend>Associated Cost Centres</legend>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Cost Centre
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="template: {name:'actividadesAsociadas', foreach: viewModel.costCentres}"></tbody>
    </table>
</fieldset>
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="actividadesAsociadas">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: NameCC"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: CostCentreId"></td>
        <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: remove">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

My javascript is:

```
function costCentre(CostCentreId, IdTransactionType, NameCC, ownerViewModel) {

    this.CostCentreId      = ko.observable(CostCentreId); 
    this.IdTransactionType = ko.observable(IdTransactionType); 
    this.NameCC            = ko.observable(NameCC);
    this.remove            = function() { ownerViewModel.costCentres.destroy(this) }
} 



function costCentreViewModel() { 

   // other methods

   this.costCentres = ko.observableArray([]);

    var self = this;self = this;
    $.ajax({url: "/[...route...]/GetCostCentres/" + @id,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (jsonResult) {
            var mappedCostCentres = $.map(jsonResult, function(item) {
            return new costCentre(item.CostCentreId, item.IdTransactionType, item.Name, self)
             });
             for (cc in mappedCostCentres)
             {
                 self.costCentres.push(new costCentre(cc.CostCentreId, cc.IdTransactionType, cc.NameCC, self));
             }
       },
       error: function (result) {
             $('#ErrorDisplay').show().html('<p>' + result.responseText + '</p>');
       }
    });
    // test data
    this.costCentres.push(new costCentre(55, 54, "test", this));

    // other methods
}; 

var viewModel = new costCentreViewModel();
jQuery(document).ready(function () { ko.applyBindings(viewModel); });
```

The bit where the problem happens in the javascript code is:

```
for (cc in mappedCostCentres)
{
    self.costCentres.push(new costCentre(cc.CostCentreId, cc.IdTransactionType, cc.NameCC, self));
}
```

The reason being that cc.CostCentreId, cc.IdTransactionType and cc.NameCC all evaluate to `undefined`.

I know that this is the case, because the test data is displayed correctly by the jquery.tmpl template, whereas the rows that have been brought in by the $.ajax call just display as empty  tags.

### jsonResult:

The jsonResult returned by the $.ajax call looks like this (this is correct):

```
    [{"CostCentreId":5,"IdTransactionType":2,"Name":"Impuestos"},
{"CostCentreId":14,"IdTransactionType":3,"Name":"Transferencias Internas"}]
```

### Questions:

1. Having set up my for in loop (`for(cc in mappedCostCentres)`), why does:

`cc.NameCC`

evaluate to `undefined`, despite being able to see in firebug that the items in mappedCostCentres have the values that I expect?

1. What better, or rather, working way is there to fill one array from another array?

Edit:

I am now trying the following code:

in my ViewModel (costCentreViewModel), I define:

```
this.GetCostCentres = function() {
    $.ajax({url: "/Admin/Accounts/GetCostCentres/" + @id,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (jsonResult) {
                var mapped = $.map(jsonResult, function(item) {
                    return new costCentre(item.CostCentreId, item.IdTransactionType, item.Name, self)
                });
                self.costCentres = ko.observableArray(mapped);
                alert(self.costCentres.length);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                $('#ErrorDisplay').show().html('<p>' + result.responseText + '</p>');
        }
    });
};
```

Then I call (from outside the viewmodel definition):

```
var viewModel = new costCentreViewModel();
viewModel.GetCostCentres();
jQuery(document).ready(function () { ko.applyBindings(viewModel); });
```

It still doesn't work.  The problem in my mind is:

Why doesn't this line work (everything else does):

```
self.costCentres = ko.observableArray(mapped);
```

I can only think it is the way I have defined my viewmodel object, using the constructor pattern, ie:

```
function myViewModel() {
this.costCentres= ko.observableArray([]);

...

this.GetCostCentres = function() {
   $.ajax(....);

}
```

but I honestly haven't a clue.  JavaScript is defeating me right now.  Maybe I should go back to Quantum Cosmology?

Comment: Can you post what jsonResult looks like?  You should not need to construct the costCentre twice.  If you want to replace the entire array, then you could just do: `this.costCentres(mappedCostCentres)` or if you want to append, then just loop through jsonResult and construct them as you push them onto costCentres.  Still if you are getting undefined, then something else is up as well.  At that point, they would be observables, so they would have needed to be referenced as a function (Cc.CostCentreId()), but if they are undefined, then again there is another issue.

Comment: @RP Niemeyer:  I have added the jsonResult returned.  I tried the this.costCentres(mappedCostCentres), but it didn't work (that was in the sample on the knockoutjs.com website.  As you say, there must be a different problem, but that is where the problem is located...

Comment: @RP Niemeyer:  I have added some extra text based on your suggestions.  Still no joy.

Comment: When you set the value of an observable, you need to pass it in as the first parameter.  So, you want to do `self.costCentres(mapped)`.  It sounds though like you tried this and it possibly failed though.  If you do `self.costCentres = ko.observableArray(mapped)` then you are setting it to a new observableArray that is not bound to your UI.  Does `mapped` seem to have the correct contents?

Comment: @RP Niemeyer:  Thanks to your suggestions, I have got it working.  Seems I was blind to having written self.costCentres = ko.observableArray(mapped); instead of self.costCentres(mapped);  Do you want to write an answer with your suggestions and I will mark it as answer, which is what is due, imo.  Many thanks either way.  The only outstanding issue is that after self.costCentres(mapped);, I had put alert(self.costCentres.length);.  Despite everything working, that alert still shows 0 as the length of costCentres.  It should show the same as alert(mapped);, surely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the main issue was that when trying to set the value of the observableArray on the result of an AJAX request, you were setting it equal to a new observableArray rather than setting the value of the existing one that was already bound to your UI.

So, `self.CostCentres` = ko.observableArray(mapped)` will create a new observableArray that your UI is not currently bound against.

`self.CostCentres(mapped)` would be the appropriate way to set an existing observableArray equal to an entirely new array.

In a previous attempt, it did look like you were constructing a CostCentre twice to push it onto your observableArray.  It is only necessary to create each CostCentre once.

Comment: Thanks RP Niemeyer.  I can only add that I got into trouble because I copied the sample on knockoutjs.com verbatim, and was too ignorant to know that I had to add some code to make the sample run.  EG:  jquery(document).ready(function () { ko.applyBindings(viewModel); });  Many thanks for your detailed help that put me back on the scent.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has largely been due to:

1. my lack of knowledge of javascript.
2. copying the knockoutjs.com tutorial for loading and saving data using knocking and not realising that the tutorial framework was missing any lines of js code to call the viewmodel object.

So when it didn't work, I set off on a number of red herrings that just drove me deeper and deeper into the mud.

Niemeyer's comments below the question helped me to get back on track.  But for anyone with similar levels of javascript ignorance as me, you can copy or adapt the tutorial code on knockoutjs.com, just remember to add, at the bottom the equivalent of (ie, depending on what your code does):

```
var viewModel = new costCentreViewModel();
viewModel.GetCostCentres();
jQuery(document).ready(function () { ko.applyBindings(viewModel); });
```

This effectively runs your code, as opposed to odd things happening, that I am not equipped to describe or analyse...

### Note

I have added this answer in case anyone comes looking with the same problem as me, and to hightlight what did work, which was following RP Niemeyer's suggestions and getting the thing to work.

If RP Niemeyer adds an answer, summarising his suggestions, I will delete this answer and mark his as the solution.